# Reset & Configure APC 2200 - Model SUA2200RM2U

Tags: ups

My company are upgraing their UPS's in their server room and asked if i would like one of the UPS's. I said yes absolutely. I work in IT and have experience with networking. My question is the network card that's installed in the UPS needs to be reset. Something I've never done before. I have a serial to RJ45 cable to connect from the ups to my computer. my question is will that work in resetting the network card so that I may log into the interface? Also to access the terminal I have been told that putty is a good program for that. I would really like to get this setup for the systems in my home. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention the card model is AP9618.

Comment: Rather than leave a comment, use the [edit] link to add additional details to your question. Also, why do you believe the network card needs to be reset?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this info on APC's web site. [Video: How do I configure APC Network Management Card network settings?](http://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA156064/?actp=LIST_RECENT)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was set with a static ip address. I'd like to change/reset that ip to configure for my own network. Is there a way to find out what that current ip address is set too?

Comment: If none of the links to the APC web support from the above comment help you, I don't know. You will probably have to ask the people who gave it to you. If you plug it into your network, do you see the device?

Answer (score 1):

You need a paper clip (to poke the reset button on the card) while its installed & powered up. Press & hold for 5 sec.

Also see [this](http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z5QDZ/ASTE-6Z5QDZ_R0_EN.pdf?sdirect=true) link to the APC website which is the pdf giving the setup guide and help for that network card.

Once you have the card reset you should be able to connect via a web browser to its default IP. The default user/pass is 'apc'

The web interface is easier/better than the serial/telnet/ssh menu system. If for someone reason the reset doesn't work then you could connect the card in its configured state to a spare ethernet port or via a laptop using an IP within the range it was configured for and access it that way (presuming you know the login details) then just change the IP and other settings via the web interface. If you don't know the IP the card had you could run wireshark against it and see what that tells you.